# Making lines thiccker when using DrawRectangleLines() In raylib

Tags: c++, game-development, raylib

I came across a problem that I cannot change line thickness when using DrawRectangleLines(), and it would be stupid to create a texture with just thicker lines, I tried to search through internet and docs and I couldn't find anything Or I am just blind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function - note the Ex suffix:

`void DrawRectangleLinesEx(Rectangle rec, float lineThick, Color color);`

---

Not every shape has a "LinesEx" counterpart. Sometimes you can call `void rlSetLineWidth(float width);` before drawing them, but that `width` isn't always used.

Circles for example, are drawn pixel by pixel and will always have a thickness of 1. You're in luck with Rectangles though.

Comment: Thanks, The answer is right, I'm very thankful for it